# Angularjs not loading properly data-binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im trying to use this angularjs random data-binding in an ecommerce, but idk why it is not loading properly. It is a recent sales popup. Can anyone help me? Here is the code https://codepen.io/ranieri/pen/qBXLapK

[clic to see the Image that shows the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpfXl.jpg)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Compras falsas</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

     <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.2/angular.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body >
    
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<section class="custom-social-proof" ng-if='!isLoading' ng-app='myapp' ng-controller='myctrl'>
    <div class="custom-notification">
      <div class="custom-notification-container">
        <div class="custom-notification-image-wrapper">
          <img id="myPicture" src={{::item[rand4].img}}>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-notification-content-wrapper">
          <p class="custom-notification-content" >
           {{::names[rand2]}} de {{::states[rand1]}}<br>
           Compró hace {{::horas[rand3]}} horas
            <small>{{::rand4+1}}x <a href="{{::item[rand4].link}}">{{::item[rand4].product}}</a></small>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-close"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
<!-- partial -->
 
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>    
   

</body>
</html>
```